# Prove that the continuous image of closed and bounded interval is a closed and bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a nonconstant function that is continuous on $[a,b]$, where $a < b$. Prove that the image of $f$ is some closed bounded interval $[c,d]$, where $c < d$.

Comment: I think you mean closed bounded interval. An interval can never be finite. It is uncountable.

Comment: yes, you can say that it is a closed bounded interval as well. What would the answer be then?

Comment: If you are familiar with topological notions like connectedness and compactness then my answer will make sense to you. If not then I think the answer by bungo is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have the topological notions of compactness and connectedness yet, then you can prove it with a few elementary facts from real analysis:

1. A continuous, real-valued function $f$ on a closed, bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ achieves its minimum and maximum values, call them $c$ and $d$, respectively.
2. By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ assumes every value between $c$ and $d$.

So you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the image of compact set under a continuous map is compact and the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected. Now a compact connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed bounded interval. So you are done.